# two view controllers are not segue same view controller one is working another is not working swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i have two view controller both are of same type and both have some detail view page view. and both have different segue name but one is going to the detail page and another isnt going throwing some error.
can somebody help me with this problem ?

Segue which is not working

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showQueueDetails"){

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        // sending data from tableviews to DetailTableView
        let passingData = segue.destination as! QueueDetailViewController
        // Getting the complete CoreData Object and passing it to the detail view
        passingData.data = coreDataArray[indexPath.row]

        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

segue which is working

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetails"){

        // var upcoming: NewViewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        //let titleString = self.objects.objects(at: sender.row) as? String

        // sending data from tableviews to DetailTableView
        let passingData = segue.destination as! RecentScansDetailViewController
        // Getting the complete CoreData Object and passing it to the detail view
        passingData.data = coreDataArray[indexPath.row]

        // upcoming.titleString = titleString
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[error which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcieY.png)

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zak9O.png)

i want to have same controller to go to another view controller
but while coming back it should automatically know which view controller it should go back

Comment: Please show your code, or the error or something to give us an idea how to help you.

Comment: "throwing some error" _What_ error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output indicates that your seque with identifier "showQueueDetails" has a targetViewController of type "RecentScansDetailViewController" (the same you got for the seque "showDetails".

Make sure that the seque with Identifier "showQueueDetails" really points to the targetViewController of type "QueueDetailViewController" as you also cast it to in your code.

Go back to your storyboard and have a look for

1. the seque itself
2. the targetViewController's Class of your seque with identifier "showQueueDetails" - maybe you copied your "RecentScansDetailViewController"-ViewController and did not update its class.